# Get auth token using post request

Tags: c#, security, oauth, jwt, token

I am trying to get request auth token by making a post web request to a url. The api expects username/password as credentials in the `form-data` payload.

When I click the sign-in option on the browser, the network logs show a `GET` request with `HTML` as response, followed by a `POST` request which returns form-data with username/password and request token in payload.

[image: Network log from browser..]

Trying to mock the flow using `webrequest`, I am doing a simple `post` request, as the following:

```
public string HttpPost(string url, string post, string refer = "")
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // request.CookieContainer = cJar;
            request.UserAgent = UserAgent;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Referer = refer;

            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

However, this request only returns the text/HTML markup of the page as the first part of the request of the browser does. How do I get it to run the subsequent `POST` to fetch the token from the endpoint?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the first `GET` Request:

[image]

Comment: Using fiddler, can you post the logs here of the requests concerned? Both request and response. The initial get request seems irrelevant if its returning html as opposed to json or xml

Comment: Seems like running fiddler on mac os is a pain in a**.. operating on Sierra 10.13.1, is there any other workaround that we can adapt to for this? Could it be that it is using some redirect url mechanism under the hood? Or the first GET is the request for cookies? Which is used for the next POST request?

Comment: Updated the question to include the response for first GET request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is a CSRF token, what you need to do is find the login form in the html response that you've received with your initial get request, and also to ensure you are storing the cookies set in this response.

You will then need to search within the html response for the hidden input parameter named 'token' next to the username and pw input fields and use the value of that element to compose your post request.

Doing this programmatically is possible with some regex or the htmlagilitypack to extract that token

Comment: Wow! Thank you sir! That is exactly what I was looking for.. after a close look at the response, I am able to locate the token embedded inside an input tag.

Comment: After extracting the request token hidden in the GET response, I am doing a post to the same uri. However, it returns some html in the response, I guess something is missing. Would I have to set the cookie in the request header for POST which I got earlier?

Comment: Exactly! Retrieve the cookies and include it in the post request

Comment: This is what I am trying now: 
`fr.getCookies().Add(new Cookie("__RequestVerificationToken", requestToken, "/", "somedomain.com"));
                var htmlPostRes = hrh.HttpPost("https://uriforserver",
                "{\"username\":\"334\",\"password\":\"131\",\"__RequestVerificationToken\":\"'" + requestToken + "'\"}",
                fr.getCookies());` 
After some read, it seems .net mvc csrf requires to match the token in cookies as well as request formdata.. This does not seem to work..